# Where can I get support or ask questions on kepler.gl?

Tags: kepler.gl

Bugs and feature requests go to the GitHub repository (https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl), where can I ask questions or get support on kepler.gl?

Answer (score 0):

you can raise an issue at https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl/issues if you think you have a distinct problem.